# Android TextToSpeech in Papiamento Languages

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm writing an Android application which needs to speak out a text (i.e the TextToSpeech functionality in an eReader). I am trying to do this in Papiamento Languages ("http://www.narin.com/papiamentu/"). Is this possible? If so, how could I do it? There are some TTS engines available. I used eSpeak TTS Engine. With the use of eSpeak, I was able to configure the settings page to use it as the default engine. But how could I use that engine to do TTS in our application? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Papiamento isn't supported at the OS level, nor do pretty much every 3rd party TTS engine. I wish it did though, saw a few people using our app when I was in Curaçao a few weeks ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only espeak supports this language, and it should be as easy as going to your android settings, general management or language and input, text to speech, preferred tts engine and select espeak as the default tts engine, which should automatically synthesize using espeak.